# class cannot be resolved to a type(jsp)

Tags: java, jsp

I am new to jsp. I was learning useBean method, and there is a example at

http://www.studytonight.com/jsp/getproperty-tag.php

Scroll down, you will find it.

Here is my jsp file:

> ```
> <html>
> <head>
>     <title>Welcome Page</title>
> </head>
> <jsp:useBean id="person" type="PersonBean" scope="request"/>   <body>
>     Hello,  <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="name"/>      </body> </html>
> ```

and here is my PersonBean.java file, compiled to class file and placed in
classes file:

> ```
> import java.io.Serializable;
> public class PersonBean implements Serializable
> {
>  private String name="Hello World";
>     public PersonBean()
>    {
>     this.name="Hello";
>    }
>    public void setName(String name)
>    {
>     this.name = name;
>    }
>    public String getName()
>    {
>     return name;
>    }
> }
> ```

I am getting the error :
An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file: /hello1.jsp
PersonBean cannot be resolved to a type

> ```
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 
>
> An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file: /hello1.jsp
> PersonBean cannot be resolved to a type
> 2:     <head>
> 3:         <title>Welcome Page</title>
> 4:     </head>
> 5:     <jsp:useBean id="person" type="PersonBean" scope="request"/>
> 6:   <body>
> 7:         Hello,  <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="name"/>   
> 8:   </body>
>
>
> An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file: /hello1.jsp
> PersonBean cannot be resolved to a type
> 2:     <head>
> 3:         <title>Welcome Page</title>
> 4:     </head>
> 5:     <jsp:useBean id="person" type="PersonBean" scope="request"/>
> 6:   <body>
> 7:         Hello,  <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="name"/>   
> 8:   </body>
>
>
> An error occurred at line: 7 in the jsp file: /hello1.jsp
> PersonBean cannot be resolved to a type
> 4:     </head>
> 5:     <jsp:useBean id="person" type="PersonBean" scope="request"/>
> 6:   <body>
> 7:         Hello,  <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="name"/>   
> 8:   </body>
> 9: </html>
>
>
> An error occurred at line: 7 in the jsp file: /hello1.jsp
> PersonBean cannot be resolved to a type
> 4:     </head>
> 5:     <jsp:useBean id="person" type="PersonBean" scope="request"/>
> 6:   <body>
> 7:         Hello,  <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="name"/>   
> 8:   </body>
> 9: </html>
>
>
> Stacktrace:
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:490)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:662)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.70 logs.
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsp:useBean action tag:

```
<jsp:useBean id= "instanceName" scope= "page | request | session | application"   
    class= "packageName.className" type= "packageName.className"  
    beanName="packageName.className | <%= expression >" >  
 </jsp:useBean>
```

1.Put `PersonBean` class in a package in order to be able to use that in another classes. Classes in the default package are invisible to classes which are by itself in a package.

2.Put the `.class` file in `web-inf/classes`.

3.Specify the fully qualified class name of the `PersonBean` in the `<jsp:useBean/>` declaration.

Furthermore - the convention for the JVM finding a default package class is to look in the "current" directory. In a server environment you have no control over the "current" directory so you have to use a package.

Modify Your Code as Below:

PersonBean.java

```
package com.person;

import java.io.Serializable;

    public class PersonBean implements Serializable {

        private String name="Hello World";
        public PersonBean()
       {
        this.name="Hello";
       }
       public void setName(String name)
       {
        this.name = name;
       }
       public String getName()
       {
        return name;
       }
    }
```

Person.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome Page</title>
</head>
<jsp:useBean id="person" class="com.person.PersonBean" scope="request"/>    
 Hello, <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="name"/>  
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't understand much of it. Could you explain the first point in detail?

Comment: @Karan Thakkar In which package you added the `PersonBean` class ?

Comment: classes="action.PersonBean". Put the PersonBean.class file in WEB-INF/classes & WEB-INF/classes/action also. Added package action; in the java file in WEB-INF/classes/action and compiled it.

Comment: @KaranThakkar Check the update section modify the code and I hope it should work. Let me know if any error.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! BTW, do you know why it wasn't working before?